# Why does equalsignorecase returns true even for non equal strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, equals

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean x;


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String igual = sc.next().toString();        

    String[] yes = new String[15];
    yes[0]="When I find myself in times of trouble";
    yes[1]="Mother Mary comes to me";
    yes[2]="Speaking words of wisdom";
    yes[3]="Let it be ";
    yes[4]="And in my hour of darkness ";
    yes[5]="She is standing right it front of me ";
    yes[6]="mama just killed a man";
    yes[7]="And when the broken hearted people ";
    yes[8]="Living in the world agree ";
    yes[9]="There will be an answer ";
    yes[10]="For though they may be parted";
    yes[11]="there is still a chance that they will see";
    yes[12]="And when the night is cloudy";
    yes[13]="There is still a light that shines on me";
    yes[14]="Shine until tomorrow";

    String[] no = new String[5];
    no[0]="I wake up to the sound of music";
    no[1]="Mother Mary comes to me";
    no[2]="put a gun against his head";
    no[3]="pulled my trigger now his dead";
    no[4]="mama life had just began";

    // searches in the yes array
    for (int i=0 ; i<yes.length ; i++){
    x=igual.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(yes[i].trim());

    if (x=true){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    }

            //searches in the no array
    for (int j=0 ; j<no.length ; j++){
    x = igual.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(no[j].trim());
    if (x=true){
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    }

}

}
```

prints 15 times true
and 5 times false
even though the string you enter equals only one of the strings in the array.
I debuged the code and those were the results
It looks like it sets the 'x' variable inside the 'if' condition
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Assignments return their right-hand side. Therefore (from your `if`-statement conditions):

```
x=true
```

always returns `true`. You were probably looking for `x == true` or, more conventionally, `x` (as in `if (x) {...}`). The simpler second variant should generally be favored.

Comment: This is one of the few occassions where this kind of mistake bites one in Java - in C this happens more often, as C has a very liberal understanding of what makes a boolean... To avoid this, either use `true == x` to avoid the condition to be mistaken as assignment, or just use `if(x)`

Comment: I strongly recommend the simple `if (x) { ... }` form.

Answer (score 3):

Use `x == true`, an equality expression, instead of `x = true`, which is an assignment expression.

The JLS, [chapter 15.26](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26), says this

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred.

So, in the code

```
if (x = true)
```

`x` gets assigned `true` and then `if` evaluates that `true`. So, regardless of the value you got from the `equalsIgnoreCase`, the statement as is will always enter the `if` block because the assignment expression will return `true`.

Also, you don't need to do a conditional check on a boolean. You can simply use

```
if (x) { // read as if x is true
    ...
}
```

Comment: *"then your `if` evaluates `x` as true"* No that's not the reason. The value of `x` itself is not what determines the outcome of the `if`-statement in this case.

Comment: @arshajii I actually looked into it and, unless I'm misinterpreting it, the JLS says _At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred._ In [chapter 15.26](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26).

Comment: Yes, that's always true, but that return value isn't retrieved/returned from looking up the variable to which it was assigned, as your answer implies. In other words, `if` doesn't *"check the value of the boolean x"* after it is assigned.

Comment: @arshajii I don't get how you interpret _the value of the variable_. If _the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable_, then the `if` does check the value of `x`.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase it. Your answer implies that the following happens: right-hand side is evaluated to `true`, `x` is assigned to `true`, `x` is looked-up and it's value is returned. In reality, this happens: right-hand side is evaluated to `true`, this value is cached, `x` is assigned to `true`, cached value of `true` is returned (by "cached" I mean duplicated on the stack). `x` is never 'looked-up' after it is assigned here. You can actually see this in the bytecode if you write something like `int x = 1; System.out.println(x = 3);` and view it via `javap`.

Comment: @arshajii With the JLS statement, I would think: right-hand is evaluated to `true`, `x` is assigned `true`, value of `x` is returned. I'll go look at bytecode

Comment: @arshajii Had to read some docs to understand the bytecode, but I got the idea. The `true` will be pushed onto stack, duplicated, popped to load `x`, and popped again for the `if`. Very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. It's a small thing and your answer had the right idea (+1).